# Выделение запятыми слова "просто"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, выделяется ли запятыми наречие "просто" в предложениях такого рода:
"Да он(,) просто(,) ничего в этом не понимает!"
То есть, является ли "просто" тут вводным словом?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, обособление не нужно. Вводным словом не является. "Просто" здесь - усилительная частица (или наречие в роли такой частицы).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не выделяется запятыми. "Просто" здесь употребляется как усилительная частица.
 См. Толковый словарь Ушакова 1935-1940. ПРОСТО *нареч*. 1.Нареч. к простой1 в 1, 2, 3, 4 и 6 знач.А ларчик просто открывался. Крылов. Нет, объяснись без оговорок и просто, прямо отвечай. Пушкин. На все это надо смотреть просто. Гончаров. Один молодой человек пишет своей любезной, сперва просто, потом в стихах. Тургенев. Петр входил не просто, — всегда как-нибудь особенно выкатив глаза. А. Н. Толстой.2.в знач. сказуемого, кому-чему.Легко, не трудно, не мудрено (разг.).Тебе п. рассуждать со стороны, а ты сам попробуй сделать.3.Употр. как усилительная частица в знач. в самом деле, вот действительно, истинно (разг.).Это просто издевательство! Чехов. Просто кишки порвешь со смеху. Чехов. Это слабость непростительная, просто детство. Тургенев. Табаком накурили, сударыня, — не продохнешь просто. А. Островский. П. загляденье! П. девать некуда!4.Употр. как ограничительная частица в знач. только и ничего больше, не что иное как (разг.).Мне просто хочется домой. Гончаров. Я Пушкин просто, не Мусин. Пушкин. Люблю тебя, сосед Пахом: ты просто глуп и слава богу. Пушкин. Я думаю, он просто якобинец, ваш Чацкий. Грибоедов. Он просто игрок умнее всех тех, с которыми ему приходится играть. Л. Толстой. Это просто враки.5.Как-то случайно, без намерения, вообще (разг.).Это непростительно глупое слово просто сорвалось у меня с языка. Тургенев.◊Просто-напросто (разг.)— то же, что просто в 3 и 4 знач., но с большей степенью выразительности.Ты просто-напросто испугался.Просто так (разг.)— то же, что просто в 5 знач., но с большею степенью выразительности.Я просто так туда иду.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые здесь не нужны: обособлять нечего и незачем.