# Просто ( ) не делай этого

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова просто?
Предложение : Просто ( ) не делай этого .

Comment: Этот вопрос, похоже, уже задавали: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: @Victor Bazarov  Немного другая фраза. Хотя ответ, конечно, тот же. Я бы не закрывал.

Answer (score 3):

Просто не делай этого .

Запятая не нужна, просто - то частица со значением "всего лишь".

Вводное слово со значением "проще говоря"из частицы не получится", исходя из структуры и интонации предложения.

Изобразить авторскую паузу можно с помощью многоточия:Просто... не делай этого .